# Renaming Experience Fragment (XF) root folder in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.5

Tags: aem

I would like to rename an Experience Fragment (XF) root folder in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.5 from `/content/experience-fragments/old_name/de` to say `/content/experience-fragments/new_name/de`. How can I do that? Many different components use this path to access the experience fragements and I have to account for all occurences.

The only options I see when I select the XF folder in AEM editor are **Properties**, **Publish** and **Delete**. In Properties there is no option to rename.

Comment: A dirty way: Use the CRXlight to rename the node